# Ajax interrupt current function without using async

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have a custom jQuery function with callbacks, in one of them i want to do a server-side check before some event is triggered.
Something like this:

```
var object = $('#object').customFunction({
     onSomeEvent: function (someData) {
         $.ajax({
                 ...
                 ...
                 success: function(data) {
                     if (data == ok) {
                         return true;
                     } else {
                         return false; *****
                     }
                 }
         })
     },
})
```

**** I want this "return false;" to be the return of "onSomeEvent".
I know i can make the ajax call async false, save the response data in a variable, check it after the ajax and return the false then, but i really would like to avoid the async false.

I really dont know what to try, everything i google is putting the ajax async on false.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: the returned value in success callback is not accessible anywhere

Comment: @Bravo is there another way to achieve what i need?

Comment: the code in `onSomeEvent` is asynchronous, therefore it can not return true/false based on what happens at *some time in the future* - you'll either need to use a callback argument (and make appropriate changes to where you call onSomeEvent) or perhaps use Promises (and again, make the appropriate changes to where you call onSomeEvent) either way, you'll need to change how you use that function - which is beyond the scope of your question, as you haven't shown how it is being used

Answer (score 0):

to avoid setting async to false, im using this..

```
my_request = $.ajax({
    ...
    ...
})

my_request.done(function(data)){
   //you can set the data to global
});
```